# Restore IIS Application Pool settings to Application defaults

Tags: asp.net, iis

latest versions of IIS allows to set Application Pool Defaults that applies to all not-changed settings of application pools and that writes  tag in applicationHost.config.
I can't find info about how to reset an app pool to defaults or force Defaults to be re-applied to app pools overwriting custom settings.
For other types of settings there's a "Revert to Parent" action that restore settings to defaults, there's something similar also for Application Pool Defaults? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately AFAIK there is no easy programmatic way to achieve that, the applicationPools section is one of those special ones that has a defaults (applicationPoolDefaults) and since it is a collection you certainly do not want to reset it to parent since that would erase all application pools. The idea is you want to remove all attributes and elements that have been set and that is very easy to do looking in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config, so you can look there for  and you'll see easily which ones are overriding values. You will also quickly see that it is not the right thing to just reset values there since you would end up changing the version of .NET or the identity or some things that might actually be correctly set on a per application basis. for example in my case you can see that the BizTalk Adapter is changing some values such as identityType and others. you could just remove all values (except name) and that truly would reset the values to the applicationPoolDefaults:

```
    <applicationPools>
        <add name="DefaultAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
        <add name=".NET v4.5 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
        <add name=".NET v4.5" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
        <add name="Classic .NET AppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
        <add name=".NET v2.0 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
        <add name=".NET v2.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
        <add name="BizTalk Adapter AppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
            <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
        </add>
```

If you are comfortable with C# I would recommend instead using something like Microsoft.Web.Administration to see what is actually set and reset the ones 
you feel comfortable, something like the following snippet would do the trick, and the nice thing is you could use the Remote capabilities of MWA to monitor servers remotely if you wanted to instead of opening the files in notepad:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

        foreach (var pool in mgr.ApplicationPools)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pool.Name);
            IterateElement(pool, "\t");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static void IterateElement(ConfigurationElement configElement, string indent)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in configElement.Attributes)
        {
            if (!attribute.IsInheritedFromDefaultValue && (bool)attribute.GetMetadata("isPresent"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}'{1}'='{2}'", indent, attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
            }
        }

        foreach (var child in configElement.ChildElements)
        {
            if (child.IsLocallyStored)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}<{1}>", indent, child.Schema.Name);
                IterateElement(child, indent + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
```